# Same namespace cannot find constructor of class

Tags: php, phpunit, slim

I am trying to instantiate object of a class A that is of the same namespace of my current class C and I fail.

Both classes are in namespace App\Models.

This is the code of A.php:

```
namespace App\Models;

class A implements B
{
    private $url;

    public function __construct($url = "")
    {
        $this->url = $url;
    }
}
```

This is the code of C.php:

```
namespace App\Models;
require_once 'A.php';

class C
{
    private $url;

    ...some functions...

    public function getC()
    {
        $test = A($this->url);
        return $test;
    }

    ...other functions
}
```

I get

```
Error: Call to undefined function App\Models\A()
```

in phpunit and I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using PHP 7.0.24

Comment: I'm guessing you forgot a `new`? `$test = new A($this->url);`? You're calling it as a function invokation as is. Can we close this question as a typographical error/simple typo?

Comment: Please answer this formally so I can note it as the answer. I was struggling with this for 4 hours. I have never felt this silly before. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `A()` you're invoking `A()` as a function. Looks like you forgot a `new`:

```
class C
{
    private $url;

    ...some functions...

    public function getC()
    {
        $test = new A($this->url);
        return $test;
    }

    ...other functions
}
```

You've made a simple typo - it happens to the best of us.